# Calling a powershell cmdlet from ps script

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a cmdlet with the following defintion:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName="Path",
               SupportsShouldProcess=$TRUE)]
param(
  [parameter(Mandatory=$TRUE,Position=0)]
    [String] $Pattern,
  [parameter(Mandatory=$TRUE,Position=1)]
    [String] [AllowEmptyString()] $Replacement,
  [parameter(Mandatory=$TRUE,ParameterSetName="Path",
    Position=2,ValueFromPipeline=$TRUE)]
    [String[]] $Path,
  [parameter(Mandatory=$TRUE,ParameterSetName="LiteralPath",
    Position=2)]
    [String[]] $LiteralPath,
    [Switch] $CaseSensitive,
    [Switch] $Multiline,
    [Switch] $UnixText,
    [Switch] $Overwrite,
    [Switch] $Force,
    [String] $Encoding="ASCII"
)
```

I put the cmdlet .ps1 file in the same folder as as a powershell script file that calls the cmdlet as following:

> Invoke-Expression -Command .\Replace-FileString.ps1 "9595" "NewPort"
>   "c:\temp" -Overwrite

However, when I execute my ps script, I get the following error:

> Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that
>   accepts argument '9595'.
>   How can I make it work? 
>   Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command '.\Replace-FileString.ps1 "9595" "NewPort" "c:\temp" -Overwrite'
```

Your command includes arguments that uses quotemarks, so PS thinks that your command is over and those are new arguments(not a part of the -Command paramter).